# Difference between Sqlalchemy scoped_session(..) and scoped_session(..)()

Tags: sqlalchemy

what is the difference between using `scoped_session` explicitly:

```
engine = create_engine(url)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

session.add(..)
session.commit()
session.remove()

session.add(..)
session.commit()
session.remove()
```

and creating instance of `scoped_session` object:

```
engine = create_engine(url)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

session().add(..)
session().commit()
session.remove()

session().add(..)
session().commit()
session.remove()
```

Sqlachemy always return the same session for the same thread by calling `session()`:

```
>> session() is session() 
True
>> session is session() 
False
```

Is that a proper way to manipulate a connection in multithreaded environment? If so, why sqlalchemy allow to querying using `session` instead of `session()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"scoped_session" returns a factory object, so you must call the factory to return an instance. "scoped_session" will actually return the same session when called from the same scope (in almost every use case, the scope is individual user requests to a web page).

So though you call session() repeatedly, it isn't actually creating multiple sessions, but the same one is being returned each time.

I recommend using a capital S to denote the fact that session is a factory and not an instance of an object.

More documentation here, going into a lot more detail than I did: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html

EDIT: Both ways will access the same object. I've always found it more clear to produce an instance from scoped_session (not all factories provide functionality like this), but both will access the the thread local session object.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#implicit-method-access

Comment: Careful with the terminology. A generator in Python is a very specific thing; a "factory" is what you are talking about.

Comment: ""scoped_session" returns a generator object, so you must call the generator to return an instance" - the best part is that I don't have to because both works: `Session.commit()` and `Session().commit()`. And the question was, what is the difference? Maybe `Session().commit()` works in mult-threading while `Session.commit()` not?

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically, the factory will automagically return the proper thread local session. I find this functionality unclear, but to each their own.